# Mysql Replication Data not updated but log updated

Tags: mysql, replication

Here are the steps i did.

I was Replicating the mysql 5.0.95 as master and 5.5 as a slave. I'm using linux OS. My DB engine is InnoDBenter code here

#### I have set the master with

```
/etc/my.cnf
**#mysql Server setup**
server-id=1
bind-address = 192.168.1.41
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
sync_binlog=1
log-bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog-do-db=my_db
```

#### I have set the slave with

```
/etc/my.cnf
**#mysql replication client setup**
server-id=5
master-host=192.168.1.41
master-user=web_master
master-password=webmaster
master-connect-retry=60
replicate-do-db=dev_my_db
log-slave-updates
```

#### I have granted permission on master as

```
GRANT SUPER,REPLICATION CLIENT,REPLICATION SLAVE,RELOAD ON *.* TO 'web_master'@'192.168.1.41' identified by 'webmaster';
```

I have set change master and bin position on the slave

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='192.168.1.41', MASTER_USER='web_master', MASTER_PASSWORD='webmaster', MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.00002', MASTER_LOG_POS=107;
```

#### I did 2 insert and a update and log my queries

and checked My Master status as

```
mysql> SHOW master STATUS\G

File: mysql-bin.000004
Position: 13790
Binlog_Do_DB: my_db
Binlog_Ignore_DB: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

#### I chcekd my slave and slave status as

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
Master_Host: 192.168.1.41
Master_User: web_master
Master_Port: 3306
Connect_Retry: 60
Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000004
Read_Master_Log_Pos: 13790
Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000007
Relay_Log_Pos: 244
Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000004
Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
Replicate_Do_DB: dev_CHGV2_dbo
Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
Replicate_Do_Table: 
Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
Last_Errno: 0
Last_Error: 
Skip_Counter: 0
Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 13790
Relay_Log_Space: 401
Until_Condition: None
Until_Log_File: 
Until_Log_Pos: 0
Master_SSL_Allowed: No
Master_SSL_CA_File: 
Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
Master_SSL_Cert: 
Master_SSL_Cipher: 
Master_SSL_Key: 
Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
Last_IO_Errno: 0
Last_IO_Error: 
Last_SQL_Errno: 0
Last_SQL_Error: 
Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
Master_Server_Id: 4
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
ERROR: 
No query specified
```

I could see the bin log are updated on slave, i couldn't figure out what was causing the issue. As my updates on the master is not replicated on slave.
can any one suggest did i have missed out something?

Comment: How many databases do you have on the slave?  If there are multiple databases have you checked tables in each one to verify no tables anywhere are getting updated?  Also where did you set the slave user/pass in the master /etc/my.cnf?

Comment: The issue is fixed- The issue was we were having the multiple database on the slave. And the master db was replicated to slave which have the same name. And i was using mysql 5.5.23 where i no need to configure master-host,master-user insted i have to set only in the change master command